# In 1916, did an amputee, invalided out of the French army, get a pension?

Tags: world-war-one

Did an amputee, invalided out of the French army, get a pension in 1916, and if so, how much in francs per year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't find any figures for the year 1916. It appears to have taken a few years for the pension program for WW1 veterans to get established.  Discussion of this can be found in the book on ***[The French Army and the First World War](https://books.google.com/books?id=DZEZBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA398&dq=france%20ww1%20veterans%20pension%20amounts%20-united%20states&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFq6zv-pvaAhXJzlQKHXLgAKYQ6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q=france%20ww1%20veterans%20pension%20amounts%20-united%20states&f=true)***, by Elizabeth Greenhalgh. Discussions began in 1919, and by 1922

> 1,117,874 disability pensions were being paid to
>   ex-servicemen.

Concerning the amount paid:

> The pension law promulgated on 31 march 1919 awarded 2500 francs to a
>   private with 100 percent disability, plus 300 francs for each
>   dependent child and 400 francs for each elderly dependent; widows
>   received 800 francs. Medical care was provided free of charge.

This figure seems to comparable to an average yearly salary at the time.

> By way of comparison, a woman typist might earn 1,800 francs a year,
>   rising to 3,600 by the end of her career; a miner in 1919 earned over
>   3000 francs.